# Android Studio Warnings with ExactTarget SDK 4.6.1

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush-android

When launching applications have heaps of warning coming from ET classes, like:

> Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   Error:(com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.ETPushConfig$1) that doesn't come with an
>   Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>   Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>   Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>   Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>   Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

Is there a way to solve this or does it require Salesforce to update update their proguard file with the following?

> -keepattributes EnclosingMethod
>   -keepattributes InnerClasses

Comment: @BillMote thanks for raising the problem of too quickly flagging/closing questions. I think it is something we should all pay attention to more. Sorry for the inconvenience, but when you have a moment, would you mind moving your answers to the actual answers? Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct!  The `EnclosingMethod` flag was missing from our Proguard config file.  I have raised this issue internally and it will be resolved in an upcoming release.  This could make it into a HotFix sooner, but you would need to raise a formal escalation through your account manager in order for this to get prioritized higher ;)

Comment: It's fine. It's not that urgent.